# switched from nvidia to amd gpu, sluggish GUI, 3D acceleration seems to run. Really confused

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu

This is Ubuntu 20.04.

I switched from an nvidia GPU to an AMD one and am struggling with restoring normal GUI usage.

At first it worked perfectly fine, but then I had the great idea to go ahead and attempt to install the AMDGPU Pro drivers, and this failed with errors in the kernel compilation step. On the next boot,  I had a black screen with blinking text cursor. I was able to go in and remove the driver using the framebuffer console, and I was able to find a more recent version of the driver, which did successfully install past the kernel step.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WlpKqttwlU

Unfortunately this yields this behavior where all windows lag like hell, could not set any reasonable resolution, and could not rotate my display, and which seemed at first to clearly lack hardware acceleration, except that glxgears as shown runs at nearly a thousand frames per second, with the painfully slow scanning drawing behavior still present. `glxinfo` shows direct rendering: Yes. So at this point I'd like to know some sane steps toward returning to that time that I had freshly installed the replacement card and everything was running.

Answer (score 0):

Well after I uninstalled the amdgpu driver with `/etc/bin/amdgpu-uninstall` and a reboot i am back in business.

I have no idea what to conclude after this experience. This is an ancient and underpowered AMD GPU (Turks Radeon HD 7570), but nevertheless it was alarming exactly the extent to which the experience ended up unacceptable with the newer drivers.

Comment: Also these drivers that come with the kernel run glxgears at nearly 7000 fps. So maybe it was still software rendering earlier.